# External entity reference in external dtd (xml)

Tags: xml, reference, entity, external, dtd

i have little bit of problem while working with External entity reference in External DTD

for Example

**[name.xml]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE simple SYSTEM "simple.dtd">
<simple>
       <name> &a;   </name>
       <age>  21   </age>
       <address> bsk street </address>  
</simple>
```

**[name.dtd]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!ELEMENT simple (name,age,address)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT age (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT address (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT a "abhijeet">
```

when i run this program on the Internet Explorer i am getting error...

Comment: Shouldn't `"simple.dtd"` read `"name.dtd"`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you're using an ELEMENT declaration to declare an entity.

This is what your ENTITY declaration should look like:

```
<!ENTITY a "abhijeet">
```

Also, you have `[name.dtd]` in your example, but your system identifier shows `simple.dtd`. Be sure your system identifier is pointing to the correct DTD.

Example of internal subset:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE simple SYSTEM "simple.dtd" [
<!ENTITY a "abhijeet">
]>
<simple>
  <name> &a;   </name>
  <age>  21   </age>
  <address> bsk street </address>
</simple>
```

Comment: but i have doubt why it only works on IE why not firefox or chrome

Comment: I don't think Firefox loads external entities (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XML_in_Mozilla). One thing that will work in IE and Firefox is adding the `ENTITY` declaration to the internal subset (between the `[` and the `]` in the prolog/doctype declaration. (I added an example above.)

Comment: Nice declaration for xml entities